# Not receiving a return message in python 2 code

Tags: python, json, string, python-2.7, function

I'm pretty new to python and just learning to ropes. In the code bellow I have a function taking several inputs from a json string. I'm attempting to have a return output in the specified strings. Problem? when I run the file I get nothing... I'm sure I'm missing something incredibly simply, but for the life of me I can't figure out what. I've attempted to use `return` as well as `print` at the end of the function. No cheese. 
Help?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import datetime, json

def jeeves(request): #defines the function
    message=''
    if request['type']=='maintainance':
        message='Thank you tenant at unit'+str(request['unit'])+', your request for maintenance to deal with '+'"'+str(request['issue'])+'"'+' has been received #2 input'
    elif request['type']=='purchase':
        message='Thank you tenant at unit'+str(request['unit'])+'your request to purchase a'+str(request['commodity'])+ ' has been received'
    elif request['type']=='reservation':
        startTime=request['date'].split(" ")[1]
        startTime=startTime.split('')
        time=0;
        num=[]
        for item in startTime:
            if isdigit(item):
                num.append(item)

        for index in range(len(num)):
            time+=num[index]*10**(len(num)-index)
        endTime=0
        daySplit=''.join(startTime[-2:])
        if time+int(request['duration'].split(' ')[0])>12:
            endTime=time+int(request['duration'].split(' ')[0])-12
            if daySplit=='AM':
                endTime=str(endTime)+'PM'
            else:
                endTime=str(endTime)+'AM'
        else:
            endTime=endTime+int(request['duration'].split(' ')[0])
            endTime=str(endTime)+daySplit
        message='Thank you tenant at unit'+str(request['unit'])+'your request to reserve our '+str(request['location'])+' on '+str(request['date'].split(' ')[0])+' from '+str(request['date'].split(' ')[1])+' to '+ endTime+' has been received'
    elif request['type']=='complaint':
        message='Thank you tenant at unit'+str(request['unit'])+' we will have someone follow up on '+'"'+request['issue']+'"'+' in regards to our '+request['location']
    return message
    print message

json.dumps(jeeves({"type":"maintenance", "unit":221, "issue":"Air filter needs replacing"}))
```

ps: I'm new to coding in general. If there is a better, more productive way for me to ask questions, I'm open to feedback. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You are returning before printing so the print statement is never reached

Comment: Print after return will not execute

Comment: you need to `print message` before `return message`, or `print message` will not execute.

Comment: Yep, `return message;print message` to `print message;return message`

Comment: Thanks! I feel kind of silly now, but that fixed it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put return before the print function because when you use return it ends a function. You might also want to check out what return actually does [here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/return.html)